# Sending msg once and stop Repeat sending message

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

I want to get user message and send it to admin via this [module](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api), That is okey in First Time, But in each `/start` command that send a duplicate message to admin.
For example in First `/start` command every thing is okey and my input is `A` and my **output is**: 

`A
Your Message Saved, Can I Send it?`

**After Send:**

`A 
User Message to Admin
Your message has been successfully sent`

In Secend `/start` my input is `B` and my output is;:

```
B
Your Message Saved, Can I Send it?
```

**After Send:**

```
B 
User Message to Admin
B 
User Message to Admin
Your message has been successfully sent
Your message has been successfully sent
```

and
In Third `/start` my input is `C` and my output is;:
above output but 3 repeat message C

How Should I Solve This?

**Code:**

```
let iMsg = null; // iMsg is null
bot.onText(/\/start/, async (msg) => {
  const opts = {
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
      remove_keyboard: true,
    }),
  };
  await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Please send your message:', opts);

  // Get User Message:
  await bot.once('message', async (msg) => { // listen once to msg
    const opts = {
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
        keyboard: [
          ['Send'],
        ],
        resize_keyboard: true,
        one_time_keyboard: true,
      }),
    };
    iMsg = msg.text; // iMsg has a Value
    await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `${iMsg}\n\n Your Message Saved, Can I Send it?`, opts);
  });
  await bot.onText(/Send/, async (msg) => {
    const opts = {
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
        keyboard: StartKeyboard,
        resize_keyboard: true,
        one_time_keyboard: true,
      }),
    };
    await bot.sendMessage('AdminId', `${iMsg}\n\n'User Message to Admin.'`, opts);
    await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Your message has been successfully sent', opts);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved ✔️

```
//Keyboards
const StartKeyboard = [
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['Contact Us']
]
//Main Script
bot.onText(/\/start/, (msg) => {
  const opts = {
    reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
      keyboard: StartKeyboard,
      resize_keyboard: true,
      one_time_keyboard: true
    })
  };
  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `Hello`, opts);
});

bot.onText(/Contact Us/, (msg) => {
  const opts = {
    reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
      keyboard: StartKeyboard,
      resize_keyboard: true,
      one_time_keyboard: true
    })
  };
  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `Please Write Your Message:`, opts);
  getmessage1();
});
// Functions
var getmessage = async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bot.once('message', (msg) => {
      console.log("User Message Is: " + msg.text)
      const opts = {
        reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
        reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
          keyboard: StartKeyboard,
          resize_keyboard: true,
          one_time_keyboard: true
        })
      };
      bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Thanks, Your Message Received', opts);
      resolve(true);
    });
  });
  return
}

var getmessage1 = async () => {
  await getmessage();
}
//END
//https://github.com/saeedhei
```